# The class number and the inverse Galois problem

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory

Let $G$ be finite group and $k$ a field. Inverse Galois theory asks if there is a galois extension $L/k$ such that $Gal(L/k) \simeq G$. Lets assume $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\mathcal{h}_L$ denote the the class number of $L/k$.

If there are non isomorphic realizations of $G$ via $L_1/k, L_2/k$, what can one say about the class numbers $\mathcal{h}_{L_1}$, $\mathcal{h}_{L_2}$?

If it is possible that they dont coincide what is the possible amount these numbers differ by?

Comment: In practice: are you asking if there exists any relation between galois group and class number? Recall that only for the case of quadratic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ the class number can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I have very little knowledge of the relation of the class number and the galois group. My main question is if there will always occur the same class number when realizing G. I suspect that this isnt true.

Comment: I am telling you that there is no reason for this to be true, and all quadratic extensions are the most enlightening example.

Comment: Ok this is great news. Now here comes the thing behind all this: How does one compute the minimal class number that will occur for a realization of G?

Comment: This will be an interesting question when you state it just that way. I’m not on intimate terms with many examples where $|G|>2$, but for the examples I know, it seems that your minimal number is $1$. But maybe you should look up tables of class numbers, to get some feel for the landscape.

Comment: Do you have a hint where i can find tables that contain both information: G and the class number of the respective field extension?

Comment: If $G = (\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})^n$ for large enough $n$ (I think $n \ge  6$ is enough), then the class group of any extension $K/\mathbf{Q}$ with Galois group $G$ will always be even, and so the minimal number is not always $1$.